# Algolia - search insights and viewed filters (Vue)

Tags: vue.js, algolia

I'm using Algolia's Vue instant search library along with their search insights library and I'm hitting a problem trying to get the `viewedFilters` event to fire. The way it's described is that when a user visits a landing page which predefines facets for a search instance it should trigger this event. I have been able to get other events to fire, such as `viewedObjectIds`, `clickedFilters`, `clickedObjectIds`, and such by using the search insights middleware. I'm not sure how to get the `viewedFilters` event to fire and track, however.

This is the doc page for the event from Algolia: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/viewed-filters/

Here's a simplified breakdown of what I have set up:

```
<template>
    <ais-instant-search
        :index-name="my_index"
        :middlewares="middlewares"
        :search-client="searchClient"
    >
        <!-- Facets / Hits / Etc -->
    </ais-instant-search>
</template>

<script>
    import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch';
    import aa from 'search-insights';
    import { createInsightsMiddleware } from 'instantsearch.js/es/middlewares'

    const insightsMiddleware = createInsightsMiddleware({
        insightsClient: aa,
        onEvent: (event, aa) => {
            const { insightsMethod, payload, widgetType, eventType } = event;
            if (insightsMethod) {
                aa('init', {
                    appId: "app_id",
                    apiKey: "app_key",
                    useCookie: true,
                });

                aa(insightsMethod, payload);
            }
        }
    });

    export default {
        data() {
            searchClient: this.createSearchClient(),
            middlewares: [insightsMiddleware]
        },
        methods: {
            createSearchClient() {
                const algoliaClient = algoliasearch("app_id", "api_key");

                return {
                    search(requests) {
                        const newRequests = requests.map(request => {
                            if (!request.params.query || request.params.query.length === 0) {
                                request.params.analytics = false;
                            }

                            return request;
                        });

                        return algoliaClient.search(newRequests);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```